# Graphics tablet

Tags: modeling, sculpting, draw-mode, tools

I’ve been trying to sculpt and I realize that I am horrible at it.  I am using a mouse to sculpt in blender and I think it would be easier to use a graphics tablet.  I have a touch screen 2 in 1 laptop that can fold to a tablet and a smart pen that works with it.  Would that setup work the same as a graphics tablet?

Comment: Hello :). Why not just try it and see? Full touchscreen support is a requested feature, you can vote for it [here on rightclickselect](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/h7dbbc/)

Comment: As a side note, one of the major benefits of graphics tablets is pressure detection. Not all touch screens support that.